# Filter columns with null objects in KendoUI Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I have the following column where i already managed how to control nulls in template and when sorting like this:

```
{
    field: "SucursalDetails.Nombre", title: "Sucursal", width: 40,
    template: "# if (SucursalDetails == null) { #" +
      "<span data-content=' '>-</span>" +
      "# } else { #" +  

      "<span'>  #: SucursalDetails.Nombre #</span>" +
      "# } #",
    sortable: {
      compare: function (a, b, descending) {

        if (a.SucursalDetails == null && b.SucursalDetails == null) {
          return 0;
        }
        else {
          if (a.SucursalDetails == null || b.SucursalDetails == null) {
            return descending ? 1 : -1;
          }

          else {
            if (descending) {
              return b.Id - a.Id;
            } else {
              return a.Id - b.Id;
            }
          }
        }

      }
```

the only thing that is left to do, is to control it when filtered. The javascript console shows "TypeError: d.SucursalDetails is null" when filtering.

How do i achieve filtering control of nulls like this scenario?

Note: Im deploying this in SpringBoot. but i dont think this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my work finally solved it.

We added the following into schema:

```
parse: function(response) {

        for (var i = 0; i < response.d.results.length; i++) {         

          //for each optional entity in your OData expand, add an entry here         

          if (response.d.results[i]['SucursalDetails'] == null)
          {
            response.d.results[i]['SucursalDetails'] = {
              Nombre: '-'
            };
          }        

        }     
        return response;
        }
```

With this code, the use of template and sortable became useless, because no object will be null.

Answer (score 0):

"The javascript console shows "TypeError: **d.SucursalDetails** is null" when filtering."

not correct because d.SucursalDetails is not used in function but I know where the issue

you can try this

```
{
field: "SucursalDetails.Nombre", title: "Sucursal", width: 40,
template: "# if (!SucursalDetails) { #" +
  "<span data-content=' '>-</span>" +
  "# } else { #" +  

  "<span'>  #: SucursalDetails.Nombre #</span>" +
  "# } #",
sortable: {
  compare: function (a, b, descending) {

    if (!a.SucursalDetails && !b.SucursalDetails) {
      return 0;
    }
    else {
      if (!a.SucursalDetails || !b.SucursalDetails) {
        return descending ? 1 : -1;
      }

      else {
        if (descending) {
          return b.Id - a.Id;
        } else {
          return a.Id - b.Id;
        }
      }
    }

  }
```